# glooedge tls not working for more than one virtual service

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, ingress-controller, gloo, gloo-edge

I am using [Gloo edge](https://docs.solo.io/gloo-edge/master/) as my ingress controller
I have two virtual services say one for  domain `a.example.com` and another for `b.example.com`.
When I add `sslConfig` for one it works completely fine. But when I add it for both I am not able to access my service, I get

`curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to a.example.com:443`

```yaml
  sslConfig:
    secretRef:
      name: secret-name
      namespace: gloo-system
```

Using the same sslConfig for both virtual services. Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue here.
I tried adding `sniDomains`  with values `a.example.com` in one and `b.example.com` in the second one. But error is still shown. When I remove sslConfig  from one virtual service it works again.

Also `glooctl check` shows

```sh
No problems detected.
Unable to cancel request for *exec.roundTripper
```

Comment: I just did this recently on 1.13.5 and have no problems. Were your ssl certs created with `*.example.com` ?

Comment: I also once missed out the sni domains that ended up with this problem. Do you have this? https://docs.solo.io/gloo-edge/1.7.23/guides/security/tls/server_tls/